# Shifting the pointer of the string in C++

Tags: c++

In C we are able to do this :

```
char *str;
scanf("%s", str); // lets say that we enter "Hello"
str = str + 2;
printf("%s", str); // and the answer would be "llo"
```

Is there something like this in C++ with string datatype in O(1) time?

**Edit : It is giving me this error ->**

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('string' (aka 'basic_string<char,
  char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >') and 'int')
str = str + 1;
```

**Edit2 : I ran this code and got the above error ->**

```
string str = "Hello";
str = str + 1;
cout << str << endl;
```

Comment: Same code will have undefined behaviour in C++ also.

Comment: @GAURANGVYAS Yes, I realised it as soon as I uploaded the question. I want to do this with string datatype.

Comment: @NeilButterworth No, with string datatype. Sorry, I edited the question.

Comment: Pointers generally work the same in both C and C++.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, I know. Thank you but I just wanted to do the pointer shifting with string datatype.

Comment: @drescherjm Please check the edits, thank you.

Comment: The last edit is helpful. You can't do it the way you want. @NeilButterworth has the solution.

Comment: C++17 also has `string_view` which would allow for forming `std::string_view::substr()` or mutating with `std::string_view::remove_prefix()` in constant time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s = "foobar";
    cout << &s[s.size() - 2] << endl;
    cout << &s[3] << endl;

}
```

Comment: One could also mention the `at(...)` feature that makes sure that the given index location is a valid position, even though this was not explicitly asked.

Comment: Thank you man, so many people downvoted the question. Maybe because I did not explain the question correctly. I think the question was quiet clear to understand after my first edit, but at least I got the answer.

Comment: @MrZ Can you please explain more? Thank you.

Comment: @AbhishekAgrawal to me your question is now clear after the last edit. You got an upvote from me as a result.

Comment: If you access the string with `operator[]` at a position larger than the actual string you get undefined behaviour. If you use `my_string.at(too_large_int)` an exception is thrown because `at()` always checks if the position you try to access is valid. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/at/ and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator[]/.

Comment: Come on, you know how to type. Type some explanation and get an extra +10 reputation.

Comment: It should be noted that strings are only guaranteed to be contiguous in memory since c++11. But to my knowledge many implementations had this even before. The null-termination without using c_str() is also only guaranteed since c++11 as far as I know.

Comment: @MrZ: The complexity of [`c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) has always been constant (O(1)). That pretty much implies, that any compliant implementation must store the controlled sequence in contiguous memory, even if not explicitly required by the C++ Language Standard.

Comment: @IInspectable Didn't Know That. Great info. Though technically I guess string could internally always store a c-string copy to comply with that requirement :)